# How can I compare a number with other numbers without writing them all out in C?

Tags: c, if-statement, trigonometry

Problem: I have IF statement `if (x == 180 || x == 360 || x == 540` and so on

How can I keep that list going without writing `180 + 180 * n` all out?

Extra info: i want to print "doesnt exist" if sin(x * M_PI / 180) is 0. It is 0 when sin(180), sin(360) and so on.

EDIT: i've tried `sin(x2 * M_PI / 180) == 0` but it doesnt work (probably because its close to 0 but not 0)

Comment: Thank you all, i got it figured out!

Comment: If `x` an integer or floating point number?  What if the value is -180, -360,...?

Comment: Please provide an answer or delete the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use modulo operand : %

```
if (x>0 && x%180==0) {..}
```

Answer (score 6):

Look into the mod `%` operator. It gives you the remainder when doing a divisions. So

```
(x % 180)
```

will be 0 for any integer multiple of 180 (assuming you're not so high that you get some odd wrap-around, say over 4 billion for an unsigned number.)

So you could use.

```
if ((x % 180) == 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (180 <= x && x % 180 == 0)
```

should do it.
Why are you using M_PI ?

Comment: If he wants to do it the complicated way with sin, that's what must be done to convert to radians.

Answer (score 2):

If `x` is an integer, you can use remainder operator in your IF statement:

```
if((x%180) == 0)
{
    // ...
}
```

Or, if `x` is not an integer, you can use [fmod](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/fmod):

```
if(fabs(fmod(x, 180.0)) < DBL_EPSILON)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A sloppy but practical test is

```
if ( fabs(sin(a)) < FLT_EPSILON ) 
   treataszero();
```

Comment: When comparing against zero, [epsilon method might not be what you want](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/).

Comment: No, it's sloppy. But usually dividing by a very small value is almost as bad as a division by zero, because the floating point unit can't cope and accuracy is lost. Generally using FLT_EPSILON as "effectively zero" is good enough, but not for serious numerical work.

Answer (score 1):

What appears to be OP's higher level problem "tried sin(x2 * M_PI / 180) == 0 but it doesnt work (probably because its close to 0 but not 0)" is the goal is to take the sine of `x` as expressed in degrees.

Rather than `x%180`, which is a problem if `x` is floating point, 
the idea is to reduces the `sin/cos` argument to a range of 90 degrees first before converting to radians.  No need to give up some precision with an EPSILON comparison.

See [c++ Sin and Cos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31502120/c-sin-and-cos/31525208#31525208) to get the exact value for many cases `n*90 degrees` and other improved accuracies.