# Cosine Taylor approximation C language

Tags: c, trigonometry, taylor-series

I'm working at something easy...I guess, but there is something that bothers me.

```
double x,t,cos_aprox,eps;
int k;
t=1.0;
k=1;
cos_aprox=1.0;`

printf("Introduceti x pentru care se calculeaza cos(x) si eroarea epsilon:\n");
if(scanf("%lf%lf",&x,&eps)!=2)
{
    printf("Date eronate!!\n");
    exit(1);
}
else
{
    do
    {
        t=t*(-1)*x*x/(k*(k+1));
        cos_aprox+=t;
        k+=2;
    }
    while(fabs(t)>eps);

    printf("Valoarea aproximativa a lui cos(%g) este %.9g. k este %d\n",x,cos_aprox,k);
    printf("Valoarea lui cos(%g), folosind functia din biblioteca, este %.9g.",x,cos(x));
}
```

It returns good results but when I choose any value over 39 radians there is a significant difference between it and library function `cos(x)`.

Comment: Works only if the argument is in the range `[-pi/4,pi/4]`. You'll need big integer math for the amount of digits of pi you need for the reduction. paper: http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.67.5616

Comment: Use `x = fmod(x, 2*pi);` before the while loop for improvement.  This will still have trouble for large `x` like `x > 1e10`.  The details of how to work `cos()` precisely over a wide range using your own code are not "something easy"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP's use of the Taylor's series suffers from numerical limitations with increasing values of `x`.  The addition of large alternating sign terms accumulate too much error.  Amend code to see these terms.

```
t = t*(-1)*x*x/(k*(k+1));
printf("%e\n", t);
```

Both sine and cosine calculation benefit with argument reduction to a
range of [-2π ... +2π].  The following is a good 1st step and will provide reduce the error for `x` over wider range.

```
x = fmod(x, 2*π);
```

Further reduction to the range [0 ... +π/4] can be employed using the usual trigonometric identities and `remquo()`. [Degrees example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31525208/2410359)

---

The trouble is that the above calculation relies on an approximate value of π.  π, being an irrational number, cannot be represented exactly as a `double`.  All finite `double` are rational numbers.  So instead *machine pi* is used.

```
// example
#define M_PI 3.1415926535897932384626433832795
x = fmod(x, M_PI);
```

---

To achieve accurate calculations over the *entire* range of `double x` requires sophisticated extended precision techniques.  Search for *Argument reduction for huge arguments: Good to the last bit*