# What "discontinuities in the error" are present in this trigonometric argument reduction?

Tags: c, c99

I have been reading [C99 Rationale](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf), where I found this mysterious excerpt (emphasis is mine):

> #### 7.12.4 Trigonometric functions
>
> Implementation note: trignometric argument reduction should be
> performed **by a method that causes no catastrophic discontinuities in
> the error of the computed result**. In particular, methods based solely
> on naive application of a calculation like
>
> `x - (2*pi) * (int)(x/(2*pi))`
>
> **are ill-advised.**

What exactly is wrong with this formula of reduction? It seems, that it looks fine, according to property of periodity, with the interval of `2*pi`.

Comment: For one thing, it gets progressively worse as *x* increases, because `2 * pi` is not equal to 2π for any representable floating point value `pi`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

π is an irrational number unable to be represented exactly by a finite floating-point value - which are all rational.

Various implementation support a constant like `M_PI` which is nearly, but not exactly π.  So the following introduces error.  Of course it is a problem if `(x/(2*pi)` exceed the `int` range.

```
double pi = M_PI;
double x;  // radians
double y;  // reduced radians.
y  = x - (2*pi) * (int)(x/(2*pi))
```

If this error is important to code is application specific.  The typical issue is with `tan(x)` where `x` is near  π*(n +1/2) and a slight variation on `x` will generate + or - infinity/`DBL_MAX`.

Some platforms supply functions for π reduction.

A good reference for this problem is [ARGUMENT REDUCTION FOR HUGE ARGUMENTS:
Good to the Last Bit](https://www.csee.umbc.edu/~phatak/645/supl/Ng-ArgReduction.pdf) K. C. Ng and the members of the FP group of SunPro

---

To reduce in degrees:

A range reduction for degrees is `fmod(x,360.0)` which can be expected to reduce `x` to the range `-360.0 < x < +360.0` *exactly*.  Better to use `remquo`: [`sind()` example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31525208/2410359)

Comment: @Grzegorz Szpetkowski Note that `y = fmod(x, 2*M_PI);` is certainly better than `y = x - (2*pi) * (int)(x/(2*pi))`.  If that is good enough, is application specific.

Comment: Hmm, I noticed `x - (2*pi) * (int)(x/(2*pi))` also introduces large cancellation for values _near_ multiples of 2*π.  The inexactness of `M_PI`, multiplication (with its round-off error) and that subtractive cancellation of nearly the same significant bits can leave the remaining bits meaningless.  With a trig function with a discontinuity near multiples of 2*π ([cotan()](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=cotangent+grpah&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#q=cotangent+graph&*)), this is problematic.

Comment: The decision to use sin(x) as its fundamental primitive rather than sin(2πx) and 1-cos(2πx) means that there's no good way for programs to precisely compute the above functions for precisely-representable values of x.  I wonder how many non-contrived situations arise where code which is interested in accuracy should ever evaluate trig functions for radian-measured angles greater than π/2?  Even if one wants to compute e.g. sin(x/1000000) [i.e. a function with a period of 2000000π] accuracy would demand that one perform argument reduction on x before doing the division (which would of course...

Comment: ...imply that it was done before doing the call].  I suspect that more often than not, code which computes sin(x) has just scaled x by some multiple of π, and that what code really wants to compute is the mathematical value of sin(x * π / roundedPi).  I know that radians are useful in calculus, but in most other applications precisely-representable fractions of circles are more useful.

Comment: @supercat Sounds like a `sin2pi(revolutions)`, etc. would be a good companion to `sin(radians)` for the situations you describe.  Much like `log(x)` has companions: `log10(x), log2()`.  The [referenced article](https://www.csee.umbc.edu/~phatak/645/supl/Ng-ArgReduction.pdf) details the way to counter "no good way for programs to precisely compute the above functions (like `sin(x)`)".

Comment: @supercat "but in most other applications precisely-representable fractions of circles are more useful." cuts to the core of good function design.  There are many goals: correctness,  speed, code/memory footprint, broadness of application. `sin()` is a good compromise, but as you have well identified, comes up short with a number of practical applications.  Thanks for your insights.

Comment: I don't see how that algorithm would be helpful to someone who wants to e.g. compute sin(2πx) within 3/4ulp for values of x near 1/8.  Multiplication of values near 1/8 by 2π would cause an error of ±1/2ulp in the argument, which would affect the result by about 0.35lsb in addition to the ±1/2 lsb introduced by rounding the result, leaving a net uncertainty of about 0.85lsb.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138351/discussion-between-chux-and-supercat).