# Modulus (Float) vs Branch

Tags: c++, c, modulus, branch-prediction

Given 2 expressions that do the same thing (`[-3.14, 3.14] -> [0, 6.28]`):

```
a > 0? a : a + 6.28
```

or

```
fmod(a + 6.28, 6.28)
```

Is there a general difference between the two in performance?

**Edit:**
Suppose such an expression is called many times (such that performance is relevant) and that the input `a` is different each time. (To make the question more directly answerable).

Comment: There is a very simple answer: Measure.  Write a benchmark and try it out (make sure the optimizer is turned on).  This is the only way to know if one thing is actually faster than the other.

Comment: Sure, but I guess I'm looking for a more rule of thumb answer. If there isn't one, then fine. But I would like to know if there is a general benefit of one over the other.

Comment: godbolt.org can be helpful for this. See the assembly your two solutions produces with gcc : https://godbolt.org/z/vEx4F9

Comment: Also, another option, [`std::clamp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/clamp) for C++.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Wow, that's interesting. It doesn't appear to let you see the compilation of 'fmod' though.

Comment: @KobeSystem That's because it should be provided by your standard library implementation. I guess it's not an ideal tool for this specific scenario. But in general when comparing solutions it's handy to take a look at the assembly.

Comment: @NathanOliver clamp is not relevant here (these 2 expressions leave 'a' untouched if it is positive, and shift 'a' to the [3.14, 6.28] range if it is negative). Regardless, I'm looking for a more general answer. François Andrieux's mention of [godbolt.org](http://godbolt.org) is more along the lines of what I'm looking for.

Comment: Usually when working with angles, one would prefer to map from [0, 2π] to [−π, π] rather than the other way around, to benefit from the increased floating-point precision near zero. Mapping a small negative value to a larger value loses accuracy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Tertiary
t = a > 0? a : a + 6.28
// vs fmod
m = fmod(a + 6.28, 6.28)
```

> Is there a general difference between the two in performance?

Of course profiling is best [@NathanOlive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53341437/modulus-float-vs-branch/53342676#comment93561783_53341437), yet as a general guide, consider optimization potential.

A compiler will typically optimize over the entire range of the type of `a`, not [-3.14, 3.14].  `t`, a simple calculation, is readily optimize-able.

Further, depending on [FLT_EVAL_METHOD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits/FLT_EVAL_METHOD), In C, `m` calculation is forced into `double` and certainly a function call.  More restrictions mean less optimization possibilities.  `t` may use an optimal FP width.

**Recommend** `a > 0 ? a : a + 6.28` as a general preferred approach.

---

> Given 2 expressions that do the same thing

But they do **not** do the same thing over domain `[-3.14, 3.14]`

About 1/4 of all `double` are in the range [0...1.0].  `m` usage of `a + 6.28` will lose at least 3 to *all* bits of precision with that addition.  Advantage: `t`.

Ranges differ:
The range of `t` is [0, 6.28]
The range of `m` is [0, 6.28), not [0, 6.28]

---

**Consideration about the higher goal**

It is apparent code is attempting trigonometric range reduction.  To do this well is harder than the basic sine. cosine, tangent calculation itself.  See [ARGUMENT REDUCTION FOR HUGE ARGUMENTS:
Good to the Last Bit](https://www.csee.umbc.edu/~phatak/645/supl/Ng-ArgReduction.pdf).

If code is starting with degrees rather than radians, consider the [advantages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31525208/2410359) of range reduction in degrees first.

---

**Bigger picture**

Depending on how `a` is derived or `t`, `m` are used, even better performance ideas are possible.  So if performance is truly a concern, the surrounding code is needed, else we are incorrectly micro-optimizing.