# Is it possible to get both the modulus and quotient of division in a single operation in C++?

Tags: c++, assembly, modulus, integer-division

I hear that when the processor does / or %, it will perform the same operation but one way it returns the quotient, the other way the remainder.

Is it possible to get both in a single operation? Maybe if I throw in a snippet of assembly code (which I've never done)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, the compiler will do it for you. Just use a divide followed by a remainder with the same operands.
https://godbolt.org/z/oK4f4s

```
void div(int n, int d, int *q, int *r)
{
    *q = n / d;
    *r = n % d;
}

div(int, int, int*, int*):
        mov     eax, edi
        mov     r8, rdx
        cdq
        idiv    esi
        mov     DWORD PTR [r8], eax
        mov     DWORD PTR [rcx], edx
        ret
```

Answer (score 11):

> Is it possible to get both in a single operation?

No, there is no such operator in C++. There is function in the standard library which does both operations: `std::div`

But this doesn't matter. Whether you have one or two operations in C++ doesn't mean that the cpu would have to perform that many operations. A half decent optimiser will be able to translate both operations into a single instruction (assuming that is possible with the target CPU).

Comment: (Or if not a single instruction, then compute the remainder from the quotient, dividend, and divisor, not redoing any unnecessary work.  e.g. ARM has a multiply-and-subtract instruction designed for computing remainder after doing division.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes. That's what the functions [`std::remquo`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/remquo) and [`std::div`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/div) do.

Comment: `std::remquo` --> "sign and at least the three of the last bits" are saved at the quotient pointer, not the entire quotient.  Useful with range reduction for [trig](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31525208/2410359) functions.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica -- interesting; I'd never noticed that. Thanks.