# SACSegmentation Linux and Windows Different Results

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, ransac

Given identical inputs and identical code, a different plane model is found on Windows compared to Linux using SACSegmentation in PCL. For one example, the identified plane on Linux has a roll angle of ~7 degrees where the Windows plane is ~0 degrees. Consecutive Windows results are identical as well as consecutive Linux results. Could this be related to GCC and Visual Studio using different sizes for types? Or Windows using a better `default_random_engine`?

[Same calculation on Linux and Windows --> different results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16744245/same-calculation-on-linux-and-windows-different-results)

[<random> generates same number in Linux, but not in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32730906/random-generates-same-number-in-linux-but-not-in-windows?rq=1)

I know the Windows plane is the better identified plane. How can I best remedy this difference so that the Linux version also finds this same plane?

Answer (score 0):

It's about the random engine. If you only run a few iterations (in relation to your cloud size) it might give unreliable results. You could try to add more plane candidates to your RANSAC engine by the .setMaxIterations( ) method to see if the results get closer to each other.